# XPages: How to convert ODT to PDFdocuments in Java

Tags: java, pdf, xpages, xdocreport

Using XDocReport library in Java, I want to use an odt template to create odt document and then convert the file to pdf file.
When ever i run my code i got the error:

```
 Error in fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.AbstractXDocReport, line 866: fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.XDocReportException: Null template engine. Set template engine with IXDocReport#setTemplateEngine
```

I tried this:

```
public void convertToPDF(DominoDocument document) {             
        if (document != null) {
            try {
                String ooFileName = "C:\\WINDOWS\\Temp\\odtFolder\\PrintFree.odt";                  

                InputStream is = new FileInputStream(ooFileName);
                IXDocReport report;
                report = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(is,TemplateEngineKind.Velocity);
                IContext context = report.createContext();              
                context.put("Body", "HelloWorld");

                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File( "C:\\WINDOWS\\Temp\\odtFolder\\PrintFree"+System.nanoTime()+".pdf"));
                Options options = Options.getTo(ConverterTypeTo.PDF).via(ConverterTypeVia.ODFDOM); 
                report.process(context,options,out);
                System.out.println("Success");


            } catch (XDocReportException e) {
                System.out.println("XDocException");
                OpenLogItem.logError(e); 
            } 
}
```

Comment: I don't know that API, but my guess is that you need a line after IXDocReport report; that sets the template engine. It probably looks like report.setTemplateEngine("some string");

Comment: yes i set the Engine with TemplateEngineKind.Velocity, do u know any other API i could use that would work with ODT document type?

Comment: Sorry, I have never worked with that. Here is a suggestion tho. Before the line that starts with "IContext", put a line in ~like~ System.out.println(report.getTemplate()). It should return "Velocity" to your console log but if it returns null or errors, then you could determine that it wasn't set properly, or is missing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you wish to use Velocity, so you need to add in your classpath the **fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.velocity** JAR which provides the implementation of ITemplateEngine with Velocity. You need too Velocity JARs and her dependencies.